# How to install dependencies for IPython Notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I downloaded [some notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ClickSecurity/data_hacking/blob/master/dga_detection/DGA_Domain_Detection.ipynb) but when I try to ru it it prints messages about some libraries not being available, like pandas, pylab etc.

How to install those libraries? And what version of those libraries needs to be installed? I installed it manually, but it still not works, because it seems like it requires different versions.

Is there any automated way to install the proper dependencies for the notebook, with the right versions?

Comment: Best bet would probably be to install a standard distribution of scientific Python like Anaconda that includes most common scientific library dependencies.

Comment: ipython notebooks do not explicitly declare dependencies. If the author did not specify the dependencies in text form, anaconda can be a nice option, as already mentioned. For remaining import errors you will have to google.